# Cut margin-left of element in half under certain window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to cut the margin-left of a div container in half under a certain window width (mobile).

I've tried this with parseInt, .css and store it temporarly in a variable. Then cut it in half and use .replace.

```
if ($(window).width() <= 590) {
    let oldmargin = parseInt($("#div").css("marginLeft"));
    let newmargin = oldmargin/2;
    $("#div").css("marginLeft").replace('rem', newmargin);
  }
```

Unfortunately the code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a new value of margin-left, try with `$("#div").css("margin-left",newmargin);`

To **GET** a value using `.css()` = `$("#div").css("margin-left")`
To **SET** a value using `.css()` = `$("#div").css("margin-left",newmargin)`

```
$('.div').each(function() {
  var oldmargin = parseInt($(this).css("marginLeft"));
  var newmargin = oldmargin / 2;
  $(this).css("marginLeft", newmargin);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.div').each(function() {
  var oldmargin = parseInt($(this).css("marginLeft"));
  var newmargin = oldmargin / 2;
  $(this).css("marginLeft", newmargin);
});
```

```css
.div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">#div</div>
<div class="div">#div</div>
```

Comment: thanks! This works perfect! Now I do happen to have more than one div and it only changes the width from the first one (ofc by id). How can I change it to apply for every div with the class name?